# I have clone using GIT a project and can't access my project in local?

Tags: github, laravel-5.3

I got following error in my browser

```
Fatal error Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not 
found in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\bootstrap\app.php:14 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\index.php(22): require() #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\app\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cloned the repository. But the repository doesn't have the required packages.

- cd project
- `composer install` (or `composer update`)
- `composer dump-autoload -o`

Run the project, and it shouldn't show these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Then you didn't actually clone it successfully or it isn't in the path you expect (C:\xampp\htdocs\app\bootstrap\app.php:14).

If you navigate to that path, what do you see?

Comment: It clone successfully but my path was localhost/project/public.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its happened when you do not push your composer.lock file.

```
composer dump-autoload

composer install --no-scripts
```

make sure everything works now as expected (no errors!)

```
composer update
```